Testing Stripe Checkout Payment with Membership page
I'm trying to test the stripe checkout payment page with a test card number provided by Stripe documentation. Whenever I enter the credentials the green checkmark appears which means the payment card has been accepted. But when it send me to the thank you page after there is a notification that says "Your contribution has been submitted to Stripe Checkout - Testing for processing.
An email receipt will be sent to xxxxx once the transaction is processed successfully."
However I have not been sent an email and it's been an hour. Also the member gets added to the membership database but the status says pending (incomplete transaction). Please let me know if you need further details.

Can you check the Civi status page CiviCRM >> Administer >> Administration Console >> System Status.
You might have a message to setup a webhook for stripe, the webhook is needed to setup as it will send response about the payments in stripe to Civi
HTH
Pradeep
